# Meteor / Mongo find a record and prune a subarray of child id's based on a child field?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-publications

I have a collection like this in Meteor:

```
TagsToArticles = {
  tag: "Tag1",
  articles: [ article1Id, article2Id, article3Id ]
}
```

The articles collections has the following schema

```
Articles = {
  permission: "private"
  ...
}
```

The tags are essentially indexed searchterms.

Each article has a permission set to "private", "group" or "public".

Right now, I'm publishing the tags like this:

```
Meteor.publish("allTags", function() {
  return TagsToARticles.find({});
}
```

And then in the client, I'm filtering the list of articles and showing only those that are public or those that are private but created by the current user.

Ideally, however, for security purposes, I'd like to do the filtering on the server-side, within the publish function itself, to prevent clients from having access to the article Ids of private articles. I do prevent the actual article objects from being accessed unless the client has the proper permissions, but I'd like to go one step further and remove the IDs altogether from the results.

So what i'm looking for is essentially a query that allows me the following pseudocode:

```
TagsToArticles.find({ articles.foreach(articleId) {
  if (Articles.findOne(articleId).permission == 'public') ||
     (Articles.findOne(articleId).ownerId == Meteor.userId())
     include articleId
  }
```

I originally thought about doing this with a function exactly like above (basically fetching all the records and then going through each one and pruning the arrays manually, then returning the updated set of records), but my understanding is that I would then lose Meteor's reactivity and the record set won't update if the underlying data changes.

In the absence of a single find() query that does the job, if there's a way to do an additional pass with a function and still return a reactive data set, I'd be fine with that solution too.

Since this is a denormalized collection anyway (the tags are also located within the articles document), I guess I could also denormalize further and include not just the article ID but the ownerId and permission. But I'm still not sure how to test individual array elements, plus if possible, I'd like to minimize the amount of denormalization I need to do...

Comment: Why you do not have tags stored in an array inside each article document? So a field `tags` which contains tags for that article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using the [composite-publish](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package.

The publish code would look something like this if I understand your schema correctly:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('articles', function() {
  return {
    find: function() {
      return Articles.find({ $or: [ { permission: 'public' }, { ownerId: this.userId } ] });
    },
    children: [{
      find: function(article) {
        return TagsToArticles.find( { articles: article.articleId } );
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

The package does a reactive join, which is actually pretty expensive. So keep that in mind and see if this is still a good choice for you.

p.s. I remember that you cannot use Meteor.userId() in publish, that's why I used this.userId

Answer (score 1):

The good thing about your problem (articles with tags) is that relations is the same for all users. So it is a property of data and not property of a request for the data. So you can use denormalization to help you here. In SQL world you want all your data to be normalized and then you use joins to combine them together at read time. In MongoDB a better approach is to use documents to store subdocuments of related data in a dernomalized fashion (so you have both original document in another collection, and a copy of it as a subdocument in the main document). Because those relations are property of data, you can simply embed those subdocuments and store them into main documents.

The issue with denormalized data is how to keep those copies in sync. How to assure that once the main document is changed, copies in subdocuments are updated as well? To address this issue, you can use [PeerDB](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-peerdb) Meteor package (I am one of authors) where you can declare relations once and PeerDB will make sure things are synced together eventually after documents are updated.

But the problem in your case is that you want to hide the entries in the `articles` array itself for those which should not be seen by the user. And this should be for different users separately. For this you can use [middleware](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-middleware) package (also I am one of authors) which allows you to compose such transformations of publish function.

So the idea is:

- denormalize into your `articles` array the IDs and also information needed to make a permission check
- then for each publish remove those IDs which user should not have access to, and remove those extra fields which were used to make a permission check

In CoffeeScript:

```
class TagsToArticles extends Document
  @Meta
    name: 'TagsToArticles'
    fields: =>
      articles: [@ReferenceField Article, ['permission', 'ownerId']]

allTags = new PublishEndpoint 'allTags', ->
  TagsToArticles.documents.find {}

class CleanArticlesMiddleware
  processArticles: (fields, userId) ->    
    fields.articles = (_id for {_id, permission, ownerId} in fields.articles when permission is 'public' or ownerId is userId) if fields.articles

  added: (publish, collection, id, fields) ->
    @processArticles fields, publish.userId
    publish.added collection, id, fields

  changed: (publish, collection, id, fields) ->
    @processArticles fields, publish.userId
    publish.changed collection, id, fields

allTags.use new CleanArticlesMiddleware()
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't even possible to make joins in Mongo and it looks even more unrealistic to make reactive datasets based on joins in Mongo database.

But do you really need reactive dataset? You can just subscribe to public and userId records in Articles dataset, subscribe to needed tags in TagsToArticles and define helper for template that enumerates articles and tags and  returns set of records. Meteor automatically updates your HTML when items in Articles or TagsToArticles changed.

> But I'm still not sure how to test individual array elements

If you have tags within articles you may go through Articles collection only and collect unique tags from public and user articles